# href = #tag or .html for navigation bar changes

Tags: javascript, html

Learning HTML/CSS/Javascript.

I've been practicing link tags with `<a href="#home"></a>` and wanted to make a simple navigation bar for Home, Profile and Settings. I was told it's possible in JavaScript to find when you click on `#home` or `#settings` and change the content that way. Is that better or worse than having individual `.html` pages if I wanted it to change only a small portion of content on a website instead of opening a totally new page?

Thanks

Comment: Seems you want to make one page website. In that if you will click on #about then it will scroll to down the page where you have declared that id and that section will be visible without opening new page.

Comment: Like this http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav/

Comment: That looks really cool, thanks for showing me that! But I actually meant like if there was only the "about" section in that githug, how to grab info for "services" and "contact" and replace the "about" section.

Comment: Then use jquery and ajax for that.